# why print(*iterable_list) return as string?

Tags: python-3.x

when I print iterable list, it will return as list but if I use * then it will print as a string rather than list.

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 13]
print(numbers)
#[1, 3, 5, 7, 13]

print(*numbers)
#1 3 5 7 13
```

normally if I use * to unpack something, it will return as list:

```
a, *b = numbers
print(b)
#[3, 5, 7, 13]
```

but why use * in print return as string? I believe I might misunderstand something or maybe I just not clearly understand something here

could anyone point me out:

1. why print(*iterable_list) return as string?
2. what is the use cases of print(*iterable_list)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, function `print` always returns `None` and never numbers or strings.

The asterisk operator converts its right operand (an iterable) to an argument list. `print(*numbers)` is equivalent to `print(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],...)`. Each of the items is printed separately - in your case, as a number.

Conversely, `print(numbers)` prints `numbers` as a list, with all the list formatting, such as commas and square brackets.

As for the use cases, I think your example is a clear illustration of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

As you just said that `*` is used to unpack something. Then from this, I think that it is again unpacking the list or something else with `*` and keeping in print this `*` means keeping it with comma separated variables and by default python print have `sep` by space so it is returning a string with space separated values.
I am not sure about this...but i thought that it should work